# What is the SS58 Format?

Tags: ss58format

I'm looking for a high level overview of the [SS58 format](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/keyring/start/ss58/)

I found [this](https://github.com/paritytech/ss58-registry/) but can't seem to find an overview description

1. What is the SS58 format?
2. Where is it used?
3. What are the whys and wherefores?

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/glossary/):

> The SS58 address format is a public key address based on the Bitcoin
> Base-58-check encoding. Each Substrate SS58 address uses a base-58
> encoded value to identify a specific account on a specific
> Substrate-based chain. These are represented by a base-58 encoded
> value to identify a specific account on a specific Substrate chain.
> The canonical ss58-registry provide additional details about the
> address format used by different Substrate-based chains, including the
> network prefix and website used for different networks.

I'm guessing that the *SS* stands for [secret string](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_core/crypto/type.SecretString.html)

See also:

https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_core/crypto/trait.Ss58Codec.html

https://web.archive.org/web/20220211124735/https://docs.substrate.io/v3/advanced/ss58/

Comment: new url for substrate SS58 docs is at https://docs.substrate.io/reference/address-formats/

Answer (score -2):

**What is ?**
SS58 is a straightforward address design intended for Substrate based chains. Everything looks great with utilizing other address designs for a chain, however this fills in as a vigorous default.
**Use:**
The fundamental thought is a base-58 encoded esteem that can recognize a particular record on the Substrate chain. Various chains have various method for distinguishing accounts. SS58 is intended to be extensible hence.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).