# How to parse an ss58 address in no_std rust

Tags: rust, no-std, ss58

*In another question
[How do I work with SS58 encoded addresses?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6513/how-do-i-work-with-ss58-encoded-addresses) the same question was addressed, this is however about how to do it without the std lib.*

**How to convert an ss58 stored in a `String` to an `AccountId32` or `[u8;32]`**

When running in rich environment, it is easy to convert from ss58 format to `AccountId32` using:

```
use sp_core::{crypto::AccountId32, sp_std};


let a:AccountId32 = sp_std::str::FromStr::from_str(&s);
```

But checking the source code in `sp-core-20.0.0/src/crypto.rs` I can see the `FromStr` trait is guarded by a feature flag `#[cfg(feature = "std")]`
and defined only when compiled in std.

It would of course be possible for me to clone and duplicate this code for `core` but is there a better way to run this conversion in a `no_std` environment?

Edit: *There is a similar question [Is there any way to convert an ss58 address to the 32 bytes pubkey?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/is-there-any-way-to-convert-an-ss58-address-to-the-32-bytes-pubkey) but the answers is all about running in a shell which is not what I'm asking for*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to convert an ss58 address to the 32 bytes pubkey?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/is-there-any-way-to-convert-an-ss58-address-to-the-32-bytes-pubkey)

Comment: No answer yet, but duplicated.

Comment: The question asks the same thing but I think my question is better phrased and more likely to be helpful in the future. Also as you point out there are no answers to it

Comment: Yep. But I hope we can close one. (maybe that one)

Comment: I believe this is not possible. And most probably this is intended to discourage passing ss58-encoded addresses to the runtime. The recommended way of passing data is with scale codec, not any string-based serialization.

Comment: @AdamWierzbicki this is not intended for the runtime, there are other places where one can run wasm

Comment: @Simson Okay, got you. Still, I'm afraid it's not possible, but maybe someone else here will come up with an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same challenge, but could not find a way.
At the end I listed my addresses as [u8;32] but using `hex-literal`for some ergonomic, and had a [std] test asserting the list against the same list of address in `ss58` format.

Comment: This does not answer my question but it solves the problem. Accepted and upvoted.