How to Convert String Address to Substrate AccountId in Runtime for Storage Map?
I am working on a Substrate runtime and would like to convert a string representation of an address, such as "5HYKElof8yaKoyCX9L...GHii4BkrgvKymz34W", into a Substrate AccountId so that I can use it as a key in a storage map.
For reference, I have a storage map defined as follows:
#[pallet::storage]
pub(super) type MyStorage<T: Config> = StorageMap<
    _,
    Blake2_128Concat,
    T::AccountId, // This is where I need the converted Substrate address
    u32,
    OptionQuery,
>;


how do you get the string representation of account in the runtime? via extrinsic or via some other source, like http call from offchain worker?

Does this answer your question? Is there any way to convert an &str into an AccountId inside a substrate pallet?

See also https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8163/how-to-parse-an-ss58-address-in-no-std-rust.

it comes from offchain worker @dastansam

Runtime should not use Strings. You can use the AccountId type directly without String conversion. Othrwise the offchain worker should do the conversion.

Thanks @AurevoirXavier but I was wondering if it could be possible to do so without modifying the runtime and just do it at offchain worker level for example

We usually do not work with ss58 formats in a runtime environment. On some higher level they should be mapped into to your actual account id type. And utility functions for ss58 format, is not available for no std.
Sometimes that format might still look useful in runtime env, for example when you write a migration for a list of accounts, and listing them in [u8; 32] array format does not look nice. In this cases I usually use hex version of addresses (with some hex crate help). And I might provide a test which asserts that list with a list in ss58 format to make a review for such PR simpler.

You can use:
AccountId32::from_str("55HYKElof8yaKoyCX9L...GHii4BkrgvKymz34W")

See this test in the Substrate repository: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/primitives/core/src/crypto.rs#L1420C11-L1420C84

This won't work in runtime.
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/a8f4f4f00f8fc0da512a09e1450bf4cda954d70d/substrate/primitives/core/src/crypto.rs#L626
